# How to format these times in R

Tags: r, datetime

I've got some unusually formatted strings that I need to get into datetime objects, and I can't find what I need from the [strptime function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime). Examples of strings that I need formatted are:

```
4/16/2018 0:00:00
8/30/2019 14:35:00
11/15/2017 8:15:10
```

I can't find any specification that matches these kinds of strings that I can use as the `format` in `strptime`. Am I going to have to format the strings first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the format `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` to convert to `DateTime`

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2018-04-16 00:00:00 CDT" "2019-08-30 14:35:00 CDT" "2017-11-15 08:15:10 CST"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("4/16/2018 0:00:00", "8/30/2019 14:35:00", "11/15/2017 8:15:10")
```

Answer (score 2):

Seem to be quite common strings for strptime. Or was there another problem?

```
x <- "4/16/2018 0:00:01"
strptime(x ,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: There was no `0` before the `4` in my `4/16/2018` example.

Comment: Oh, yes, true. I automatically added the 0 xD But still works without the 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is enough:

```
library(lubridate)
dates = c('4/16/2018 0:00:00', '8/30/2019 14:35:00', '11/15/2017 8:15:10')
dates = mdy_hms(dates)
dates
```

Output:

```
[1] "2018-04-16 00:00:00 UTC" "2019-08-30 14:35:00 UTC" "2017-11-15 08:15:10 UTC"
```